# A verb for a mine “producing” ore

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

What verb can I use to say that a mine produces ore? The ore is not produced at the mine site, however, so I need a word for describing the whole operation (excavation, processing, etc.).

The operation I want to describe is the following. The ore is excavated and processed to some degree (simple processes to separate valuable minerals from the gangue, comminution) on site.

Is there a verb that describes the generic operation of a mine?

*Excavation* sounds a bit too specific to me, but as I am a non-native, that might be a wrong impression.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking: of course the ore is _produced_ (= excavated or mined) at the location of the mine, but it may be _processed_ elsewhere. There is no single word that would be automatically understood to encompass both the mining and the processing without additional explanation.

Comment: The removal of the ore from its natural position in the earth can be termed _mining_ or _extraction_. The concentration of the metal components of the ore through melting, fusing, and chemical alteration comes under the general term _smelting_.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but if I were to assume you meant a mine that from which ore is actually being extracted, versus one from which no ore is being extracted, you would use the word "working".  I realize that this is not a verb, which is what you're asking for, but I don't think a verb would work in this case.

- a *working* mine is a mine from which ore is currently being extracted
- a non-working mine would normally be referred to as *disused*.

A number of my ancestors were active in prospecting and mining in Northern California during and after the Gold Rush.  When I was 9 years old, my father and mother took me on a trip to visit one of my great uncles who actually had a gold mine on his property, literally in his backyard.  But because of the low-price of gold at that time ($35 per ounce) the mine was not worth working, and so it was blocked off -- it was a disused mine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**yield**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yield).

> to give forth or produce by a natural process or in return for cultivation.

"*Utah mine [**yields**](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1338&dat=19600130&id=PClYAAAAIBAJ&sjid=GvcDAAAAIBAJ&pg=4105,6811079) ore.*"

Answer (score 0):

**Mining**: is a general term used for the operation described.

- The process or business of extracting ore or minerals from the ground.

Answer (score 0):

A prolific mine yields an abundance of ore.